# jquery calling select box, how to select that and use it for later

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this function which shows options dropdown box. The box works and it whows users but when i select a user and then want to use it for further i dont know how. Any help here would be much apritiated.

After this code i have some more entries with user adds via keybord and then a submit button. All this data is then saved to database.

At this moment all data is corectlly saved exept this "Ime in priimek" which i am reading from php

```
Ime in priimek: <select id="ime_priimek" name="ime_priimek" onchange="myFunction() >

<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "smartronik";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT ime_priimek FROM smart_zaposleni");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option value=\"rezultat\">" . $row['ime_priimek'] . "</option>";
}
?>

</select>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("ime_priimek").value;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}
</script>
```

Comment: So you just want to get the value from a `select` element?  `$('#ime_priimek').val()`?

Comment: i want to use a value from select dropdown menu to be posted into database

Comment: And what's stopping you?  It sounds like what you're looking for are introductory tutorials on a variety of technologies.  Stack Overflow doesn't provide that.

Comment: i dont know how to implement this on a select dropdown box called with ajax

Comment: Getting a value from a form element is very introductory jQuery functionality.  Start with some tutorials on how to use jQuery.  Make at least *some* attempt.  We can help with specific issues you encounter, but we can't really teach you how to write code entirely.

Comment: i dont uderstand where should i put .val(), cant figure this out

Comment: You'd call `.val()` on the jQuery selector for the element for which you want to get the value.  *Exactly* as demonstrated in my first comment above.  I don't know what attempts you're making, but you're really better off starting with an introductory tutorial any time you try to use a tool or technology that you've never used before.

Comment: In every example i can find, they have select option inside html. But i am calling option with ajax to my html site. I tried using .val like this $('#ime_priimek').val(). But still dont get it to work

Comment: Well, of course any examples are going to have a `<select>` as part of the HTML.  That's because `<select>` is an HTML element.  It wouldn't make sense to have it anywhere else but the DOM of the HTML page.  You can modify the HTML dynamically via JavaScript, which sounds like what you're doing.  But that doesn't change the fact that the DOM is still just HTML.  You claim that you made some attempt, but the code in the question shows *no* attempt.  Nobody here can help you with code you're not showing.  So far all you've asked is how to get a value in jQuery, and that's been answered.

Comment: I have updated my post.  Tried using onchange function but cant get it to work

Comment: Aside from the typo where you don't close a double-quote in the `select` tag, it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/jv99cjfn/1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121094/discussion-between-jan-and-david).